# Dynamically Change AJAX WaterMark Text

Tags: c#, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got a TextBox on my page that has an AJAX TextBoxWaterMarkExtender hooked up to it.  I need to change the watermark text depending on a selection in another section of the page (which causes a partial page postback).  Here's the code I have so far:

```
    if (myConditionIsTrue)
    {
        lblShipToHeader.InnerText = string.Format("{0} Name:", AnimalTypeName);
        wmAccountName.WatermarkText = string.Format("New {0}", AnimalTypeName);
    }
    else
    {
        lblShipToHeader.InnerText = "Ship To:";
        wmAccountName.WatermarkText = "New";
    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working.  On the initial page load, myCondition will be false; setting the WaterMarkText to "New".  However, once I make a selection, the watermark text doesn't change.

The section of the page that this lives on is getting updated, as I can see the changes to lblShipToHeader.

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so maybe I should debug a bit more before I post, but I found the answer.

When the page posts back, my TextBox.Text property is set to the watermark text.  So, since the TextBox.Text is not null or empty; the watermark isn't displayed.

Simply adding this right before the snippet of code posted above fixed the problem:

```
    if (txtAccountName.Text == wmAccountName.WatermarkText)
        txtAccountName.Text = string.Empty;
```